# solve outgoing interface for entries in routing table,

Tags: networking, data-structures

below is the routing table of a router. I need to resolve the Outgoing Interface for entries whose outgoing interface is --. Theses entries are in a text file. I need to resolve the outgoing interface by solving the nexthop (longes prefix match) . 
                                                                                            for e.g. - For finding outgoing interface for 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0  the nexthop is 172.20.20.57. I take this nexthop and look in Destination column to find the longest prefix match which is 172.20.20.56 and it has a outgoing interface which is FastEthernet0.
    So outgoing interface for 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 is FastEthernet0. 
The problem is the table can have 2000-3000 entries. One of the data structure I thought of was a trie. are there any existing API that I can use to find the longest prefix match or some suggestion to solve this problem. I am using Java.

```
Destination   Network Mask    NextHop        OutgoingInterface
192.168.231.0 255.255.255.0   192.168.255.1  --
172.20.20.56  255.255.255.252 11.11.11.11    FastEthernet0
192.168.201.0 255.255.255.0   192.168.255.1  --
0.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         172.20.20.57   --
192.168.255.1 255.255.255.255 192.168.255.1  Serial0
```

Comment: Do the entries change often? If not, you can cache the "OutgoingInterface" value for all destinations and clear them when there is a relevant change to the routing info. That way, you search once for each destination, cache the result, and then use that until something changes.

Comment: yes I do plan to cache the result but that does not solve my problem of finding out the outgoing interface.

Comment: If the destinations are stored in some type of ordered list, and you then performed a "less-than-or-equal-to" on that list, would you get the entry you need?

Comment: no they may not be sorted.

Comment: Well, you don't have to sort them "in place". You can always maintain a separate sorted list of keys that points to the actual entires. In fact, you mentioned a Tree, which would be the same thing. if you don;t have that man y entires, simply go thtough them sequentially and check, remembering the degree of match, and keep a ref to the current max.